# PWA blank page Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app where one of the options you have to sign-in is Facebook, everything goes well and if you're in the browser the login works really well. The problem happens when you add the website to your mobile and it opens in PWA and you click log-in from Facebook it opens a blank page and it doesn't redirect to the app, if you close the page, go back to the app and click again facebook the user is logged in, but does anyone has any idea how to get rid of the white/blank page?

I have tried 'redirect_uri' and 'display: touch,' but none of this seems to be working anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Again, welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

A blank page after login is a common problem when using Facebook as a sign-in method, especially when we’re in development mode.

It happens because you already logged in and authorized the app, so when it tries to log-in again, it goes blank.

The most straightforward way to fix this is first to check if the user has already logged in and authorized your app before calling the .login() function.

Luckily, Facebook provides a function to do it, where they handle (almost) everything for you.

**The getLoginStatus() function**

The getLoginStatus() functions determines 1) if a user is signed into Facebook and 2) if the user has already authorized your app.

There are three possible states for a user:

- The user is logged into Facebook and has authorized your app, in this case, the function will return: connected.
- The user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your application, in this case, the function will return: not_authorized.
- The user is either not logged into Facebook or explicitly logged out of your application, in this case, we don’t know which one is it, that’s why it returns: unknown.

For example:

When we call getLoginStatus() we’ll get an object similar to this:

```
    {
  authResponse: {
    userID: '12345678912345',
    accessToken: 'kgkh3h4gkh3g4k2h4gk23h4gk2h34gk234gk2h34AndSoOn',
    session_Key: true,
    expiresIn: '5183738',
    sig: '...'
  },
  status: 'connected'
}
```

There you can see there’s an authResponse object and a status object. We’ll focus on the status object first, checking for each of the three possible responses.

```
    this.facebookProvider.getLoginStatus(response => {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // User Authenticated and your App is authorized

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // User authenticated but your app isn't authorized yet.
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

Try this and try to logout first from Facebook before you make call from PWA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this didn't worked either. I'm still getting a blank page when user clicks login on pwa. If you close the window you're connected to the app tho but I don't know how to redirect without you having to close the window.

Comment: Hi, See what facebook auth doing is popping up login window for you and redirecting back to the your website. Basic thing in that is the popping up browser window is a new browser with standalone style. PWA is an itself standalone browser. So you are just opening standalone browser in another standalone browser. The only way to get rid of it is first logout from fb and then only add pwa and after try to login using fb auth. As we use pwa as an application we dont need everytime to login. Its one time process I mean.